# How can I connect a Vue.js frontend with java backend?

Tags: javascript, java, web, vue.js

I'm developing a project with a team in which we need to create a simple CRM. Some people recommended us Vue.js to create a great looking UI, but the problem is that with the team we mainly use java. So, we wanted to know if it's there a way in which we can connect a UI made with Vue.js with backend made in java. Any recommendations on how to do it? I've searched a bit and some articles say we can use java+tomcat to connect the Vue.js UI. We need to know if these kind of integration is possible before starting to spend time into making the UI in Vue.js if we can't connect it with our java backend.

Thanks.

Comment: Vue.js is for better structuring your front-end JavaScript code, not for making an attractive UI. (CSS frameworks like Bootstrap and Foundation are tools for making an attractive UI.) You can certainly use any kind of server-side technology you wish, and that includes Java+Tomcat--your front-end Vue.js app won't know or care about what your server-side technology is.

Answer (score 7):

I did an example of a project that integrates a java api (built with spring boot) and a vue.js frontend. It uses [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to build the frontend and copy it into the resources.

The source is in my [github repo](https://github.com/gpaulo00/spring-demo)

Answer (score 1):

Yes is possible, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897615/can-you-implement-vue-js-in-a-java-ee-web-application)

you will use your java application which is your "backend" as web service.